# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null [] even though div exists

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set property of HTML with div and it throws an error saying "cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null.

In JavaScript,

```
function find_person() {

    ...

    var title = 
    "<div class=\"w3-container\">" +
    "<h3>Find a person</h3>";
    "</div>";

    document.getElementById("content_title").innerHTML = title;
}
```

In HTML,

```
<div id="content" class="w3-display-container w3-container">
    <div id = "content_title" class = "w3-row" >Title goes here
    </div>
    <div id= "content_main" class = "w3-row">
    </div>
</div>
```

Could you help me figure out what causes an error of recognizing div?

Comment: How/when/where is `find_person()` called?

Comment: could you try:
var title = document.getElementById('nameofdiv');

Comment: @Ramona it returns null.

Comment: @Pointy <a onclick="find_person()" href="javascript:void(0)" style="text-decoration: none;" ></a>

Comment: Would you try placing your script below the document?  To ensure the doc loads first because you are calling elements that must be loaded first.

Comment: @Ramona if the function is not run until a button is clicked, that's not the problem.

Comment: @ejshin1 are you getting any errors in the developer console (other than the `null` complaint)? Are you **sure** that the element id is spelled exactly the same way both in the HTML markup and in the JavaScript code?

Comment: Oh wait, I see the problem.

Comment: @Ramona I placed a script below the document. so it looks like <body>....<script></script></body>

Comment: Yes, try that out.  Also it might be easier to debug if you made a jsfiddle.  That way we can examine the file and syntax etc

Comment: @Ramona it's possible to use this site directly instead of jsfiddle via a Stack Snippet. (It's pretty much the same idea as jsfiddle, but it's right here.)

Answer (score 3):

Your "content_title" div is null when you are trying to access it.

There is high possibility that your document isn't fully loaded when you call your function on it.

Comment: Again, if the function isn't called until that `<a>` element is clicked, this is not likely to be the problem. (It *might* be, but only if the OP has failed to tell us some very important things about the page.)

Answer (score 1):

Your initialization code for the HTML content you want to add is broken:

```
var title = 
"<div class=\"w3-container\">" +
"<h3>Find a person</h3>" + // <----- "+" instead of ";"
"</div>";
```

As it is, you're trying to append an *incomplete* block of HTML, so the browser just ignores it.

Comment: Note that this does not explain the `null` returned from the `.getElementById()` call, but that's probably due to some error not included with the posted code. If there really is an element with that id then that part of the code would work.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that error. However, it seems an error is still there.

Comment: @ejshin1 well again, if you *really* have an element with the id "content_title" in your document, then `getElementById("content_title")` will find it. Browsers are not broken in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the html, you put your "Script" Tag anywhere under the  you're looking for or even best all the way under the 's closing tag. When javascript asks for id's and/or classes from its parent folder for manipulation it looks from top to where it's initialized not below. :D

Answer (score -1):

its simple with jQuery library (if you need pure js please clarify that in title)

html code:

`<a href="#" class="specific-button">button</a>`

js code:

```
function find_person(){
   var title = '<div class="w3-container">'+
                  '<h3>Find a person</h3>'+
                '</div>';

   jQuery("#content_title").html(title);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('a.specific-button').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();// this will prevent button to refresh the page
        find_person();
    });

});
```

and consider that you should split strings in this way in javascript:

```
var sample = 'first part'+
'second part'+
'third and last part';
```

semicolon is just for the last part.

Comment: If the OP's code doesn't work, then your version won't work either. The `.getElementById()` function works properly in all modern browsers (and almost all not-so-modern ones).

Comment: I didn't downvote but there are two issues: 1) recommending jQuery (or any library) when that library is not tagged on the question is generally frowned-upon; and 2) as I said in my other comment, if your code works then so should the OP code.

Comment: It seems this code removed my error. However, I want the the function to be run when the button is clicked. If the code runs before a user clicks the button, it will update part of divs.

Comment: @ejshin1 edited. but keep it in mind this is jQuery approach not pure js